# Issue with hd images in cocos2d

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have two types of images in my project. Those are,

```
sample.png , sample-hd.png
```

when i run my project i am getting the below log

```
cocos2d: Filename(sample-hd.png) contains -hd suffix. Removing it. See cocos2d issue #1040
```

What is this log?

Comment: For future readers, could you add the line of code where you're referencing the file? I'll be able to write a more complete answer that way.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the "-hd" suffix from wherever you're referencing the file, and this log message should go away. Cocos2d will automatically add back the "-hd" suffix when appropriate.

For example, this line of code:

```
CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"sample.png"];
```

will load "sample.png" on non-retina devices and "sample-hd.png" on retina devices. See [The -hd suffix](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3ahow_to_develop_retinadisplay_games_in_cocos2d#the_-hd_suffix) for more information. Here's the key bit:

> Each file opened by cocos2d (image file, config file, sprite sheet, etc…) is opened using the CCFileUtils class. When RetinaDisplay is enabled, this class will try to open the ”-hd” file instead. If that file doesn't exist, it will open the originally requested file.

Comment: i have same image with different sizes. one for retina and another for non-retina. how will i differentiate the images for retina and non-retina devices in the project.